# SublimeText encloses lines in white rectangles

Tags: syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, sublimelinter

It's rather annoying and I can't seem to figure out why.

[image]

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Looks like you have [SublimeLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2) installed. It highlights errors and warnings.

Comment: control + shift + p or cmd + shift + p and type sublimelinter and click the one with disable

Comment: in my case it is anaconda plugin

Comment: in my case it is pylinter

Comment: Note: Anaconda warnings are visible in the status bar, NOT as hover tooltips.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was Anaconda linting which I had to turn off.

Comment: It can be due to Anaconda as well, to disable it, use cmd + shift + p or control + shift + p, in the drop down menu, there will be an option, 'Anaconda: Disable linting on this file'.

Comment: In my case it was: "Highlight Duplicates: Toggle Highlighting"

Answer (score 165):

If you still have a problem with those solutions suggested above (with anaconda lint):

Disable linting altogether within the user-defined Anaconda settings file, Anaconda.sublime-settings, via the file menu: 
Sublime > Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings – User: 
When it opens file, just type the following and save it away ;-)

{"anaconda_linting": false}

At least, it fixed my problem. 
Blessings
(a debtor)<><

Comment: I want to have the linting functionality, I just want it to only highlight what is wrong and/or indicate a mistake in the gutter, not make these annoying boxes around everything.

Comment: change "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "outline", to "none" and "anaconda_linter_underlines": true, to false - you will still have gutter marks showing errors but not the annoying outlines/underlines >.<

Comment: @JamesBurke: I ended up using your suggestion which ended up running linter without the annoying outline/underlines. Here is what my **Anaconda.sublime-settings** file looks like:

`{"anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none", "anaconda_linter_underlines":false}`

Answer (score 43):

Disabling Annaconda linting in sublimetext 3 for current file:

1. Enter command palette by Cntrl + Shift + P or Command + shift + P for Mac OS X
2. Type `Anaconda: Disable linting on this file` and hit enter
3. To re-enable linting `Anaconda: Enable linting on this file`

Disabling linting persists between sessions.

[Source](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/#toc_32)

Answer (score 36):

You probably can change `"anaconda_linter_mark_style"` to `"none"` and keep `"anaconda_linter_underlines"` as `true`. This way it'll only put a underscore under errors but not highlight the whole line.

Comment: Works well, thanks! Entire Anaconda default settings file: https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/blob/master/Anaconda.sublime-settings

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to disable SublimeLinter completely, you can set Syntax Specific Preferences. 
 `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Sublime Linter -> Settings Syntax Specific User`

The preferences is evaluated similar to CSS, it cascades. Think about the most user-specific, syntax-specific rules evaluated last.

E.g: I also do not like the white rectangle, so I opted for fills.

```
 {
  /*
        Selects the way the lines with errors or warnings are marked; "outline"
        (default) draws outline boxes around the lines, "fill" fills the lines
        with the outline color, and "none" disables all outline styles
        (useful if "sublimelinter_gutter_marks" is set).
    */
    "sublimelinter_mark_style" : "fill",

    /*
        If true, lines with errors or warnings will be filled in with the
        outline color.

        This setting is DEPRECATED and will be ignored in future
        versions. Use "sublimelinter_mark_style" instead. For backwards
        compatibility reasons, this setting overrides "sublimelinter_mark_style"
        if that one is set to "outline", but has no effect if it's set to "none".
    */
    "sublimelinter_fill_outlines": false,

    // If true, lines with errors or warnings will have a gutter mark.
    "sublimelinter_gutter_marks": false,

    // If true, the find next/previous error commands will wrap.
    "sublimelinter_wrap_find": false,
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the outlines are very annoying.

Answer (score 7):

For Anaconda/Sublime Users

I have Anaconda and the lint function is useful, but out of the box, it is draconian about style.   When you hover over the rectangle, it will tell you the number of the rule it is enforcing.  You can disable the ones that you feel are unneeded or get in the way as you code.

On Macs:

1. Go to Preferences | Browse Packages | Anaconda | Anaconda.sublime-settings
2. Search for "pep8_ignore"
3. Add the rules you want to remove.

I've put in my list the following rules that remove some of the white space rules that slow me down but keeps the "no tabs" rule.

```
    "E201",
    "E202",
    "E203",
    "E302",
    "E309",
    "W291",
    "W293",
    "W391"
```

You'll want to set  "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true in your user settings if you go with this list.

Alternatively you can set "pep8" to false to stop it entirely.

Answer (score 6):

**If you are using [Anaconda](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/) plugin** (for Python development) this is it's linting functionality - it highlights Python syntax errors and [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) violations.

You can disable this feature completely or  **change the color** of this outline by adding some custom rules to your current SublimeText theme:

1. In Sublime Text menu: `Preferences > Browser Packages...`
2. Locate source file of your current theme in opened directory (*.twTheme file with the name corresponding to the one, selected in `Preferences > Color Scheme > ...`)
3. Duplicate this file, add another name (for example `Tomorrow-my.tmTheme` from `Tomorrow.tmTheme`)
4. Paste the following code to this newly created theme file, right *before* `</array>` tag:

   ```
   <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>anaconda Error Outline</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>anaconda.outline.illegal</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#FF4A52</string>
       <key>foreground</key>
       <string>#FFFFFF</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
   <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>anaconda Error Underline</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>anaconda.underline.illegal</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#FF0000</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
   <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>anaconda Warning Outline</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>anaconda.outline.warning</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#DF9400</string>
       <key>foreground</key>
       <string>#FFFFFF</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
   <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>anaconda Warning Underline</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>anaconda.underline.warning</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#FF0000</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
   <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>anaconda Violation Outline</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>anaconda.outline.violation</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#ffffff33</string>
       <key>foreground</key>
       <string>#FFFFFF</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
   <dict>
     <key>name</key>
     <string>anaconda Violation Underline</string>
     <key>scope</key>
     <string>anaconda.underline.violation</string>
     <key>settings</key>
     <dict>
       <key>background</key>
       <string>#FF0000</string>
     </dict>
   </dict>
   ```
5. Adjust the colors to your needs. Save file.
6. Select your "new" theme in `Preferences > Color Scheme >` and observe the changes.

Point 3. was needed in my case because color wasn't updated immediately, after just saving theme and restarting Sublime/switching themes (sublime uses some kind of buffer?..). So, maybe you will have to repeat steps 3-6, when you want to play a little with the colors.

Source: [Anaconda's Docs](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/IDE/#toc_50)

Answer (score 4):

On line 300 "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none", in Preferences -> Package Settings -> Anaconda -> Settings - Default. This removes the "annoying" highlighting but still checks for pep8 errors

Answer (score 3):

If none of the previous solutions worked for you, try this:

1. Go to Preferences | Package Settings | Pylinter | User settings
2. In the file, just add/modify the following lines:

   ```
   "run_on_save": false,
   "disable_outline": true
   ```

It worked for me, and in my case I had anaconda only as a folder, associating the python compiler of Sublime to the python compiler (python.exe) present in the anaconda folder.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that this can also randomly happen on the last word that you searched. So if you searched for "integer" for instance. Then all instances of "integer" will have that white square around them.

Answer (score 2):

In Anaconda with Sublime Text, if you don't want to make any changes to the settings:

In the case highlighting occurs, you can use a keyboard shortcut (in my case it's CTRL-ALT-R) to autoformat the code! The highlighting will be gone immediately.

You just have to repeat that every once in a while, after having added new code (which is not formatted according to the PEP8 rules).

The command is "anaconda_auto_format".

Comment: Thank you! this shortcut is magical. Also, if you move the cursor to the highlighted line, you will find an explanation at the bottom bar of SublimeText, stating the PEP8 violation made.

Answer (score 1):

if you got the anaconda linting

go in the dir like this C:\Users\giova\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\Anaconda
and change the anaconda.sublime-settings (find the anaconda linter keys and set them to false). See if you installed other linter stuff and change their settings to false where it seems to rely on linting until everythings is right for you. I had installed different linters, so I had to change all of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable warnings in anaconda.sublime-settings
 via the file menu:

> Sublime > Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings – User:

In opened file type following code and press `Ctrl + S` to save file

```
{"pep8": false}
```

you can also type this:

```
{"anaconda_linting": false}
```

but it disables both warnings and errors, which is not good

Answer (score 0):

For me, on sublime 3 this was the PyLinter Package. While the linting feature's useful i also wanted to get rid of the annoying highlight. Found this on their docs if it's helpful! :) 
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pylinter
I was able to remove the highlight with `Command + option + x`

```
The plugin can be invoked by a keyboard shortcut:

OS X: Command+option+z
Linux, Windows: Control+Alt+z

**Toggle Marking**

The marking of the errors in the file can be toggled off and on:

OS X: Command+option+x
Linux, Windows: Control+Alt+x
```