# circles around lines - sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

These dots on the very left and circles around lines have started appearing on my sublime text3. Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SublimeText encloses lines in white rectangles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles)

Comment: duplicate of sublime text?

Comment: thank you, finally gone!

Answer (score 4):

if you install **Anaconda** plugin for python development.
To remove circle go to **prefrences > package settings > Anaconda > settings-Default**  now search for "anaconda_gutter_marks : true" change this to **false**