# Sublime text 3 wrap the line of code with box after saving the file

Tags: python, django, sublimetext3

I am trying to learn python/django, whenever I write code in sublime text 3, initially it won't wrap the line of code with box. after saving the code ,sublime text 3 wrap  python(django) code with the boxes. This strange behavior happens only with django/python code. This annoys me a lot and I can't fully concentrate in my code.

But the other code it works perfectly

[image]

Is there a solution how to get rid of this

Comment: Maybe the same problem than [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles)?

Comment: Yes, There was a pylinter package enabled , On disabling the pylinter packages those boxes around the Line of code are gone