# White rectangle is wrapping when typing in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I got a problem while using Sublime Text from version 2 to 3. I'm using version 3.
I recorded the problem at: http://screencast.com/t/nDYm8MKYSu2D

When I type some text such as abc, a white rectangle is wrapping the text, then I click on where else, start typing, it comes back the text abc. It's weird because I don't meet this on Windows.

Packages is used:

```
{
    "bootstrapped": true,
    "in_process_packages":
    [
    ],
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "GitGutter",
        "Package Control",
        "SideBarEnhancements",
        "Theme - Spacegray"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @sergioFC: it's not duplicated, I checked that post and try to uninstall Lint package, but it's not solved

Comment: Ok, I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: @TaiPhatLam did you *completely* restart Sublime after uninstalling SublimeLinter? Please [edit] your question and post the list of plugins in **`Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings-User`** (you don't need to post the whole file, just the list of packages).

Comment: @MattDMo: I will post it when coming home. I restarted the app after uninstalling but not have a luck

Comment: OK, just @mention me in another comment when you've updated your question.

Comment: @MattDMo, hi, I edited the post

Answer (score 1):

This has actually been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles), it's SublimeLinter which highlights errors and warnings.

Comment: I checked that post and try to uninstall Lint package, but it's not solved