# unknown rectangles around comments and code in sublime text

Tags: python, sublimetext3

I am using Python and sublime text 3 on Macbook Air. When I use sublime text3 open the .py file, there are some annoying white rectangle around my codes and comments.

The rectangles around comments show:

> block comment should start with '#'

The rectangles around the head of a function show:

> too many blank lines

The rectangles around the keyword in python show:

> unexpected spaces around keyword/parameter equals

The code is here

```
import pylab
#set line width
pylab.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 6
#set font size for titles 
pylab.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 20
#set font size for labels on axes
pylab.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 20
#set size of numbers on x-axis
pylab.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 5
#set size of numbers on y-axis
pylab.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 5

def findPayment(loan, r, m):
"""Assumes: loan and r are floats, m an int
Returns the monthly payment for a mortgage of size
loan at a monthly rate of r for m months"""
return loan*((r*(1+r)**m)/((1+r)**m - 1))
```

And the problem is like
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is the PEP8 linter advising you that your code is not adhering to the style-guide expected. If your goal is to meet PEP8 standards, you should listen to those comments and fix what it says. You probably have SublimeLinter installed. Unless SublimeText 3 now includes its own?

Comment: If you did install SublimeLinter, then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles)

Comment: Sublime has no linting support built in. This is definitely a user added package.

Comment: @idjaw in my case, it seems that it is because I installed anaconda. Thanks so much!

Comment: You can see the errors or suggestions at the bottom, when you select the line, Its PEP8 suggestions, you can disable it by `shift`+`crtl`+`p` and select `Anaconda: Disable linting on this file`