# Disable rectangles in Sublimetext3

Tags: sublimetext3

Suddenly these rectangles appeared around my code, and I don't know how disable it. Could you help me?

The rectangles:

[image]

And my package enables:

```
Anaconda
backrefs
dateutil
markupsafe
mdpopups
PlainTasks
pygments
Pylinter
python-jinja2
python-markdown
PyV8
SFTP
SublimePythonIDE
User
ActionScript
AppleScript
ASP
Batch File
C#
C++
Clojure
Color Scheme Default
CSS
D
Default
Diff
Djaneiro
Emmet
Erlang
Go
Graphviz
Groovy
Haskell
HTML
Java
JavaScript
LaTeX
Lisp
Lua
Makefile
Markdown
Matlab
Objective-C
OCaml
Pascal
Perl
PHP
PlainTasks
Python
R
Rails
Regular Expressions
RestructuredText
Ruby
Rust
Scala
SFTP
ShellScript
SQL
TCL
Text
Textile
Theme Default
User
XML
YAML
0_package_control_loader.sublime-package
1Self.sublime-package
1337 Color Scheme.sublime-package
AutoFileName.sublime-package
Bootstrap 3 Autocomplete.sublime-package
Bootstrap 3 Snippets.sublime-package
BracketHighlighter.sublime-package
Djaneiro.sublime-package
Emmet.sublime-package
FileDiffs.sublime-package
Nettuts+ Fetch.sublime-package
Package Control.sublime-package
PyV8
ReadmePlease.sublime-package
```

I try to click in the white breakpoints with the right button, but nothing happens, but with the left buttons it shows this list, but I don't know what every point the list does.

[image]

And only occurred with python code, with other code like html, css or java don't appear the rectangles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the next solution, this problem would be a problem with anaconda package

[SublimeText encloses lines in white rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles)

I use the next steps:
1-Disabling Annaconda linting in sublimetext 3 for current file:

- Enter command palette by `Cntrl` + `Shift` + `P` or `Command` + `shift` + `P` for Mac OS X `Type Anaconda: Disable linting` on this file and hit enter 
  To re-enable `linting Anaconda: Enable linting` on this file

And 
2-On Macs:

Go to Preferences | Browse Packages | Anaconda | Anaconda.sublime-settings
Search for "pep8_ignore"
Add the rules you want to remove.
I've put in my list the following rules that remove some of the white space rules that slow me down but keeps the "no tabs" rule.

```
"E201",
"E202",
"E203",
"E302",
"E309",
"W291",
"W293",
"W391"
```

You'll want to set "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true in your user settings if you go with this list.

Answer (score 0):

It's the line breakpoints - used to stop the execution of code at certain points for debugging.

Click on the small white circles on the left to disable

[image]

Comment: Don't work, other time I disable the package SublimePythonIDE and BracketHighlighter, but now it isn't work.

Comment: You click them? the circles? Try right clicking and remove breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

ctrl + shift + p and disable anaconda linting, it worked for me